# Android: How to place a button end of a textview with multiline text?

Tags: android, layout, textview

I want to place a button at end of the textview paragraph, like as "Go" button that when user click on it the app going to another page.

for example:

```
if you have good endurance, 
for killing the monster you must 
going to section 2. [Go->]

-if you haven't good endurance, 
flee to section 3. [Go->]
```

in above example `[Go->]` is a tiny button that must placing exactly in end of line.

how I can do it in runtime?

Comment: I dont know about it at runtime but i can help you on how to do it in xml,if its ok with you

Comment: yes please, I can change it or at least I get the idea form it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use spans for this.

Let's assume you have a `TextView` called `myText`.

```
Drawable goButtonDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.go_button);

String text = "If you have good endurance, for killing the monster you must go to section 2. [GO]"
String replace = "[GO]";

final int index = text.indexOf(replace);
final int endIndex = index + replace.length();

final ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(goButtonDrawable, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
final ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override public void onClick(View clicked) {
        // Do your [GO] action
    }
};

SpannableString spannedText = new SpannableString(text);
spannedText.setSpan(imageSpan, index, endIndex, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannedText.setSpan(clickSpan, index, endIndex , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

myText.setText(spannedText);
```

Obviously this could be better abstracted (you could just make a custom TextView that handles this internally), but that's the general idea.

Comment: are you sure about `Spanned spannedText` ? because the Spanned don't have `setSpan` method

Comment: Should be Spannable or SpannableString instead, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks but app crashed with this exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (12 ... 4) has end before start

Comment: See the edit, I had length and indices mixed up. This was all written from my head, untested, so you may need to make some more minor modifications, but try it with the above change (endIndex)

Comment: yes, I found it too just after post comment ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the text as `html`

Append the HTML img tag to your text and set it to text view like this

```
  String htmlText = "Your multi line text <img src=\"ic_go_icon\">";

  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText, new Html.ImageGetter() {

  @Override
  public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
  int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable",getPackageName());
 Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
 drawable.setBounds(0, 0,    drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return drawable;
    }
}, null));
```

But handling the click will be for complete text view.

Comment: thanks, if I set the textview to clickable so I don't need to that button.